# Unable to add stored procedures to EDMX file in VS 2022

Tags: c#, sql, .net, visual-studio, edmx

I am wondering if anyone can recommend a possible solution or something I have not tried to help me solve the following problem.

**Issue:**

I am unable to add stored procedures to a EDMX file using the designer.

**Notes**

I am able to run the procedures via SQL management studio.

The procedures I am adding do not contain any complex field types or logic they are a basic selects for example.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[pTestProc]
AS
BEGIN
--ID is a INT and ItemName is a String
SELECT Id,ItemName FROM dbo.Items
END
```

**Odd things of note**

I am able to add and modify table structures using the EDMX designer.

**Things I have tried**

1. Closed and restarted machine.
2. Closed and restarted VS.
3. Run VS as administrator.
4. Confirmed connection string to database is correct.
5. Confirmed permissions are ok and I am able to run the procedures.
6. Confirmed procedures work ok.
7. Rollback VS to a older version (There was a recent update).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After trial and error the issue for myself turned out to be a issue with a trusted certificate. To correct this I removed the old connection string and then re-added it. Which solved the issue.

Comment: Your answer is helpful, you can make it mark so that it can help more people